# How can I get a web-hosted kmz file to project correctly when added as a layer to an arcgis online map?

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-online, kmz

I have a kmz file hosted on dropbox that I would like to display in a map through arcgis online. The kmz file was generated from an esri grid raster. I have tried altering the raster projection prior to converting it to a kmz but this appears to have no effect.

You can see the arcgis online map [here](http://bit.ly/1Bkw1Uc).

In [google maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/109870948/KMZ_Files/baarwa_com3.kmz&output=classic&dg=feature), the kmz is displayed without any errors:

Has anyone encountered this problem before and perhaps encountered a solution as well? I would just use google maps to display this data instead of arcgis online but it seems they won't be supporting kml files after February.